# Go Autocert throwing error 'missing server name'

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, ssl

**TLS Disabled**

I have developed a GoLang application and deployed it on AWS ECS (Elastic Container Service) using Fargate as the service. Initially I tried with disabling `TLS`, everything was working fine, and I could access your application using the Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) URL without any issues.

**TLS Enabled**

I decided to enable TLS (Transport Layer Security) for added security using the "go lang autocert" package. After configuring TLS and deploying the updated application, I noticed a specific error in the application logs:

`2023/09/16 07:13:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.100.184:13735: acme/autocert: missing server name`

This error indicates that there was a problem during the TLS handshake process when a client attempted to establish a secure connection with your application. The error message mentions "missing server name," which suggests that the client expected a specific server name during the TLS handshake but didn't receive it.

This most likely scenario is that this error is occurring during the initial health check performed by AWS's Target Group listeners. The Target Group listeners are checking the health of your application, and this check seems to be triggering the TLS handshake error.

I have also looked into `autocert` code this is exactly what is happening.

[image]

I am guessing listener trying to access application using IP but not a dns name. I guess this is causing error.

I tried replicating same in local by starting the server on `127.0.0.1`, when I tried accessing using `121.0.0.1:8090` I got `missing server name`. I tried by configuring a local dns record `127.0.0.1 localhost.myapp.com` in `/etc/hosts`. When I tried `localhost.myapp.com` this time I am getting `missing certificate` which is expected.

How to fix this?